# Does the integral of an operator be compact implies that the semigroup is compact?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, compact-operators

Let $M$ be a compact metric space and
$$\mathcal C^0(M) :=\{f:M\to \mathbb R;\ f\ \text{is continuous}\}.$$

Consider the semigroup of  contractive bounded linear positive operators
$$\{P^t : (\mathcal C^0(M),\|\cdot \|_{\infty}) \to \left(\mathcal C^0(M),\|\cdot\|_{\infty}\right)\}_{t\geq 0}, $$
i.e.
$$\|P^t\|\leq 1,\ P^0 = \mathrm{Id}\ \ \text{and} \ P^{s+t} = P^t \circ P^s,\ \forall \ s,t\geq 0,$$
and $$ f\in \mathcal C^0(M),\ f\geq 0 \Rightarrow \ P^t f \geq 0,\ \forall\ t\geq 0.$$

Assume that there exist $K,\alpha >0$, such that
$$ \|P^t\|\leq Ke^{-\alpha t}.$$
and

\begin{align}
G: (\mathcal C^0(M,\|\cdot\|_{\infty}) &\to \left(\mathcal C^0(M),\|\cdot\|_{\infty}\right)\\
f&\mapsto \left(x\mapsto \int_0^\infty \left(P^t f\right)(x)\ \mathrm{d}t\right)
\end{align}
is a compact operator.

> **Question:** Do $G$ being a compact and $P^t$ presenting exponential decay imply that there exist a $t_0>0$ such that $P^{t_0}$ is a compact operator?

In my head, it is harder to $G$ be compact than to $P^t$ be compact, but I was not able to prove it. Can anyone help me?